# How do vm know the physical status of NIC card?

Tags: esxi

I got 2 physical servers and 1 NAS.    Each server has been installed with esxi 8.0 U2 OS.  Each esxi has 3 VM (1 linux, 2 window).   2 Linux VM is set up with HA pacemaker without quorum. Four vm (2 vm as DC, 2 vm as window failover cluster) with nas as quorum have been configured as window failover clustering.

Currently if i unplug the physical network cable (heartbeat interconnect)with two linux VM and plug back the network cable, both linux vm will become active and the linxu vm wont know the status of network card(pacemaker service still running).   Previously we set up 2 other physical servers (baremetal suse os not esxi os)for linux suse pacemaker and if we unplug the heartbeat network card , the pacemaker service will stop running as a result two linux servers will not be active active.  How do i configure esxi such as a way that the vm know the actual state of physical nic card